# Are [cocoa] and [cocoa-touch] still relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags

The usage guide for [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) is:

> Cocoa is Apple's application-development framework for macOS, consisting of Foundation, Application Kit, and Core Data. Use the "cocoa-touch" tag for iOS questions.

This seems to be of very little sense to me considering that there is a [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) tag. Please let me explain why.

As is written in the description, `Cocoa` is a subset within `macOS` which should be used for questions about `Foundation`, `Core Data`, `AppKit`, etc. It bothers me that each of the above mentioned frameworks have their own tags.

Why is the [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) tag still relevant?

If there is a question about Core Data related to macOS why should it be labeled with tags:

[macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) [coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredata) instead of [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) [coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredata)?

P.S. In my view the story is identical for [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) and [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) are specific sets of frameworks used to develop for OS X and iOS, respectively.

[osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) are operating systems. Not all development targeting OS X and iOS uses the Cocoa or Cocoa Touch frameworks. Plenty of web-development questions, for example, may need to stipulate [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) for something that only impacts that platform.

Therefore, I don't believe they are synonymous and shouldn't be merged.

Comment: I do get the fact that iOS and OS X can be used without cocoa or cocoa-touch component being relevant. However, can you name me at least one example where "cocoa" can be used without some other tag (like "coredata") making it useless?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk - Sure. Plenty of people follow the larger [cocoa] tag to see all incoming questions that have to do with the Cocoa frameworks, but don't follow the more refined framework tags like [core-data]. If a question only has [core-data] as a tag, and not one of these larger tags, it gets far less visibility and is less likely to be answered. It's very useful to have the one broader tag, accompanied with the more specific tags.

Comment: Cheers, that clarifies things quite a bit. I will then start using those tags myself now :)

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk: I sort of agree that the way these tags are _generally_ used is redundant, but they do have their purpose: [osx] [objc] [cocoa] [nsarray] means "The question is about `NSArray` in Cocoa on OS X, using ObjC", as opposed to [osx] [objc] [gnustep] [nsarray] or [osx] [swift] [cocoa] [nsarray].

Comment: @JoshCaswell that was my main point. In addition, a lot of the times people are just ignoring them. For example by putting [ios] [coredata]. However, as both you and Brad have explained, these tags should be used